# How to deal with local links where url does not change using VBA Excel?

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I have just learned some VBA Excel and now I'm trying to get some data from a website. But before being able to get to these data, I have to click on one of the local links directing me to another webpage *with the same url*. My goal is to retrieve an array with the names of all possible local links (all club names in this case) and to be able to click on one of these.

I can find all information I want in the HTML document shown in the DOM Explorer tab in the F12 Developer Tools, so if I can access this in VBA my problem is solved. But from what I know (I couldn't find any information on this) I can only access the document shown in the Debugger tab. And the local links I'm looking for seem not to be in there.

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "http://www.knkv.nl/competitie/algemene-info/competitie/club/"
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop
Set html = ie.Document

Dim frame As Object
Set frame = html.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0)
```

I hoped to find everything in the only iframe object in this document, but this seems to be not the case as well. Any information on how I can find / deal with these local links where the url does not change is appreciated!

Comment: Where are the links you are looking for? Are they inside the iframe?

Comment: If you go to the website you can click on all club names. But if I click F12 to open the html document (the document in the Debugger tab is the one I have in my variable 'html'), I cannot find these links. Based on the webpage structure, I expected them to be around this iframe, but it does not seem to contain much information. So I'm actually clueless where the links are, that's the problem.